# Sympy Call symbols created using a range

Tags: python-3.x, call, sympy, symbols

I'm trying to be able to create symbols for a DH table, but rather that write it out, create a function. However, I don't know how to call the variable when making the table. Here is a synopsis of the problem:

```
from sympy import *


def naming_symbols(N):
    theta = symbols(f"theta:{N}")
    L = symbols(f"L:{N}")
    alpha=symbols(f"alpha:{N}")
    d=symbols(f"d:{N}")
    pprint(theta[:])
    pprint(L[:])
    pprint(alpha[:])
    pprint(d[:])
    return theta, L, alpha, d


naming_symbols(3)
print(theta2)
```

returns:

```
"*FileName*", line 18, in <module>
    print(theta2)
NameError: name 'theta2' is not defined
(θ₀, θ₁, θ₂)
(L₀, L₁, L₂)
(α₀, α₁, α₂)
(d₀, d₁, d₂)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the same for "theta_2" and "theta"

How do I call the created symbols? As in, I want to put "theta2" in the table, but it doesn't recognize it as a created symbol. I think I need to add the symbols into a dictionary or something, but don't know how to do that either. I thought the creation would add it to the dictionary... but... well, please help.

Comment: `theta` is a python variable, not a symbol.  Your prints show it is a tuple of symbols.

Comment: moreover, theta is a local variable, at least you should do: 

    `theta, L, alpha, d = naming_symbols(3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between the Symbol (a python object that SymPy creates) and the variable that you assign it to. You already know that you can call a value like 1 anything you want:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 1
```

The same is true for a Symbol that you create.

```
>>> my_x = Symbol('x'); my_x
x
```

The convention is to often use a variable name that matches the Symbol name, but this is not necessary. Notice that printing `my_x` (the variable) shows `x` (the Symbol).

The `symbols` command creates a tuple of Symbols. You can call that tuple anything you want, just like you can with numerical values

```
>>> v = (1, 2); v[0]
1
>>> my_v = symbols('v:3'); my_v[0]
v0
```

Your function is creating tuples of Symbols. You are assigning (and returning) those tuples from the function. In order to use those locally *outside* of the function you have to create python variable names for the elements of the tuples or you can access them by index just like for the tuple `v` defined above:

```
>>> one, two = v  # assigning names for the tuple elements
>>> one
1
>>> v[1]  # using index to the tuple name `v`
2

>>> naming_symbols(2)
(θ₀, θ₁)
(L₀, L₁)
(α₀, α₁)
(d₀, d₁)
((theta0, theta1), (L0, L1), (alpha0, alpha1), (d0, d1))
>>> t, l, a, d = _  # assigning names to the tuples
>>> t[0]
theta0
>>> t0,t1 = t  # assigning names to the elements of a tuple
>>> t0
theta0
```

___ probably stop here, but note...

It is possible to create names for the variables locally using the `var` command instead of the `symbols` command. It is probably better for you to learn how to do the above, but this is an example of using `var`:

```
>>> def do(n):
...     var(f'y:{n}')
...
```

Until this function is run, y0 is not defined

```
>>> y0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y0' is not defined
```

But after running it with n=3, y0, y1 and y2 will exist in the local namespace of python:

```
>>> do(3)
>>> y0
y0
>>> y1
y1
```

Note that the naming convention -- calling the SymPy symbol by the matching variable name -- is used. This only works if you create Symbol names that are valid python variables names. So although `var('x(1)')` will create a Symbol with the name `x(1)` you cannot type this to use the variable:

```
>>> var('x(1)')
x(1)
>>> x(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not callable
>>> y=_  # assign the name y to this Symbol
>>> y
x(1)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I was wondering what the difference between symbols and variables were, and just decided to use var() when I wanted to return a variable defined numerically... later in the code... during substitutions. And then, only because it was faster. I still can't get the problem to solve, though :(

Comment: `var` is only used to create Symbols. It is not a way to pass values back from a function.